# How can you create a local JavaScript database tied to a Safari-5 extension?

Tags: html, safari, local-storage, safari-extension

I was playing around trying to create a small safari extension, most for the fun of it and to see what you could do etc.

Anyways I was thinking about storing some data for my extension in a local database, so I always would have it where I needed it, across page loads.

I searched a bit on google and found this snippet from the Safari Reference Library, that will create a JavaScript database:

```
var shortName = 'mydatabase';
var version = '1.0';
var displayName = 'My Important Database';
var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
```

This works pretty well and creates the database like I wanted. The only thing is, that this database is domain specific, so my script creating the database will create a database for each domain visited, which wasn't exactly what I wanted.

So how can you, if possible, create a local storage database, that can be assigned to an safari extension, so it will be available on all domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be to do it from the global page instead of from an injected script. Problem is, it won't work.

Creating an offline database from a global page triggers a `SECURITY_ERR`. It is a known bug, and it should be fixed in the next release.

So, *right now*, there's no way to do it.

**EDIT** As Brian points out, this issue is fixed as of Safari 5.0.3. You have to specify a database size quota in Extension builder, and then it should work.

Comment: That's too bad, I guess I'll have to brace myself.

Comment: This should be fixed in the latest version of Safari. Are you still seeing a SECURITY_ERR when you try on Safari 5.0.3?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen extensions that use HTML5 databases. One thing you have to do is set an explicit quota in the extension builder, or else you will continue to get the SECURITY_ERR, forgot to mention that.